# WPF Datagridcomboboxcolumn binding to row value

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I have a datagrid in my application. Within this grid i do have two datagridcombobox columns.
Everything is working as expected, the only struggle i have is to set the itemssource of the second combobox to the selected value of the first combobox to gain access to properties of the given value.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="itemcategoriesViewSource" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type local:itemcategories}, CreateList=True}"/>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="maincategoriesViewSource" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type local:maincategories}, CreateList=True}"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource itemcategoriesViewSource}">
    <DataGrid x:Name="itemcategoriesDataGrid" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource itemcategoriesViewSource}}" EnableRowVirtualization="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="nameColumn" Width="*" Header="name" Binding="{Binding name}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="alternative_nameColumn" Width="Auto" Header="alternative name" Binding="{Binding alternative_name}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="alternative_name2Column" Width="Auto" Header="alternative name 2" Binding="{Binding alternative_name2}"/>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="maincategories_nameColumn" Width="Auto" Header="Main Category" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource maincategoriesViewSource}}" DisplayMemberPath="name" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding subcategories.maincategories}"/>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="subcategories_nameColumn" Width="Auto" Header="Sub Category" DisplayMemberPath="name" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding subcategories}">
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="ItemsSource/subcategories, ElementName="maincategories_nameColumn"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="ItemsSource/subcategories, ElementName="maincategories_nameColumn"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    TestEntities _context = new TestEntities();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource maincategoriesViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("maincategoriesViewSource")));
        System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource itemcategoriesViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("itemcategoriesViewSource")));
        // Load data by setting the CollectionViewSource.Source property:
        this._context.maincategories.ToList();
        this._context.itemcategories.ToList();
        maincategoriesViewSource.Source = this._context.maincategories.Local;
        itemcategoriesViewSource.Source = this._context.itemcategories.Local;
    }
}
```

Image of DB setup: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIgO9.png -> i'm not allowed to include it.

The idea is simple. I want to show a list of all values within itemcategories (that's why i use it as datacontext in my grid) and in another column i'd like to display a dropdown with the main categories (selected value is bound to /itemcategories/subcategories/maincategory_id) and the tricky part is to show the column with the subcategories based on selected maincategory.

Comment: Can you provide some code, to get working sample?

Comment: Hi, yes, edited my question with more informations.